# Ajax Loading Icon Not Displaying on Ajax function - Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

For some reason, my Ajax loader icon is not showing and hiding as it should. Here's my snippet of jQuery code that handles the ajax call. I can see the #loading DIV with Chrome's Developer Tools...the problem lies is that jQuery is not showing the DIV (inline style set to `display:none` on the div itself). If I remove that inline style, it shows up where it should...

Anything I'm missing here?

```
//website URL grab - Ajax call
$('.loadBTN').on("click", function(){

    var check_url = $('#web_address').val();

    if (!check_url || check_url == 'http://') { // form validation
        //alert('Please enter valid URL');
        // Do nothing
        return false;
    };

    var web_url = {
        url: $('#web_address').val(),
        ajax: '1' // needed for controller, to verify that request is ajax
    };         

    //display ajax loader animation
    $('#loading').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/web_embed',
        type: 'POST',
        data: web_url,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#ajaxContent').html(msg); // output success in this container
            $('#loading').hide();
        } 
    });        


    return false;
});
```

Comment: In your browser console when the page is open, if you try `$('#loading').show();` what happens?

Comment: Not even sure what you mean mate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest subscribing to all ajax start/stop events, independently of who's responsible for it:

```
$("#loading")
    .ajaxStart(function(){ $(this).show(); })
    .ajaxStop(function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

The loading will appear as soon as there is an ajax request, then hide when there is no ajax requests ongoing...

See http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: Where do you suggest I put this in my function? i tried something similar...to no avail.

Comment: Let's say before the end of body tag, as long as the element with id "loading" exists whenever this javascript is executed

Comment: Not working...no error. Zip. Replaced the .show() function with this...the one outside the $.ajax function

Comment: You don't have to put it in your function, this code will know when there is a global ajax request and showing the loading accordingly

Comment: Remove any `$('#loading').[show|hide]()` in your function, include the code provided just before the `</body>` tag in the page.

Comment: Here's my DIV if it makes any difference. Ignore the inline stylying. It'll be transferred to CSS. `<div id="#loading" style="display:none; position: absolute;margin: 50px auto;height: 31px;left: 475px;z-index:9999;"><img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" height="31" width="31"/></div>`

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out!

Comment: For everyone who has double and triple-checked their element ids and has still not gotten this to work, I had to attach the ajax events to the document instead of to my loading overlay: `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){$("loading").show();}).ajaxStop(function(){$("loading").hide();}`.  I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 and attaching the ajax events in $(document)ready().

Answer (score 2):

A much cleaner Ajax request IMO.  Makes use of `Context` and `BeforeSend`

```
var scope = $("#container"); // wrap in a container div to use as the context

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/web_embed',
        type: 'POST',
        data: web_url,
        context : scope,
        beforeSend : function(){ // use beforeSend 
            $('#loading').animate({
                'display'   :   'block'
            });
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            $(this).html(msg); // $(this) == context => #container
        } 
    });
```